# How to Create an Android Modal Popup with Animation?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, modal-dialog, alert

I'm trying to create a modal popup effect in Android similar to [this](https://youtu.be/WnlPZbSnlLI?t=10s) (10 seconds in). I'd like to pop up a 'window' with a TextView and WebView on it, with an animation and with the background blurred or dimmed. I've already searched and come across AlertDialog, PopupWindow, and Activity Dialogs but I'm not sure which of those, if any, are most suitable. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dialog for this:

```
public class AppDialog extends Dialog {

 View mainView;
 public AppDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
 super(context);
 mainView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.app_date_picker_dialog,null);
 addContentView(mainView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 }
}
```

Call in your activity:

```
AppDialog dialog = new AppDialog(context);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you animate the dialog popping up and closing?